# MYSQL group by hour and sum diff but separate results by hour

Tags: mysql

I have following data set

```
start_time              end_time
2017-09-12 12:08:55     2017-09-12 12:10:57
2017-09-12 12:15:10     2017-09-12 12:19:27
2017-09-12 12:24:54     2017-09-12 12:25:35
2017-09-12 12:27:32     2017-09-12 13:20:25
2017-09-12 13:20:25     2017-09-12 13:22:23
2017-09-12 13:32:01     2017-09-12 13:33:57
2017-09-12 13:45:15     2017-09-12 13:46:38
2017-09-12 13:52:52     2017-09-12 13:54:20
2017-09-12 13:59:28     2017-09-12 14:02:32
2017-09-12 14:04:37     2017-09-12 14:07:34
2017-09-12 14:12:49     2017-09-12 14:13:03
2017-09-12 14:34:09     2017-09-12 14:35:47
2017-09-12 14:40:52     2017-09-12 14:46:46
2017-09-12 14:51:57     2017-09-12 14:54:28
```

I am trying to find the sum of time differences grouped by hour. Since some blocks start in one hour but end in the next this sum calculated not the way I want. for an example if we take 2017-09-12 12:27:32 - 2017-09-12 13:20:25 total diff of this gets added to the 12th hour and ignored from 13th hour.

I'm using following query to group and sum

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(start_time, "%H") as h, 
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(start_time))) AS timediff 
FROM history 
WHERE start_time BETWEEN '2017-09-12 12:00:00' and '2017-09-12 15:00:00'
GROUP BY hour(start_time)
```

And getting the result

```
h   timediff
12  00:59:53
13  00:09:49
14  00:13:14
```

Is there a way to break blocks like 2017-09-12 12:27:32 - 2017-09-12 13:20:25 and add the difference separately to the respective hour blocks within mysql?

Preferred output

```
h   timediff
12  00:39:28
13  00:27:42
14  00:15:46
```

(From 2017-09-12 12:27:32 - 2017-09-12 13:20:25, 32m 28s should go to 12 h block and 20m 25s should go to 13h block)

Comment: Can you show example of the output you want...

Comment: Edited to add expected output

Comment: If I have understood correct, then you want minutes and seconds for each hour spent. So if start time of 12th date is 9 and end time of 12th is 11, you want is 1 for 9, 1 for 10 and 1 for 11 but currently it shows 3 for 9. Right?

Comment: can a time range span at most two different hours? three? any fixed number?

Comment: @KaranDesai correct. these time are actually from a call center call duration.

Comment: @ysth these time are actually from a call center call duration. calls normally don't last more than few minutes. Maximum time diff would be around 30min. So if the time start and end lay in different hours it will be 2 diff hours next to each other almost all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql sub-query for this. first divide data to each hour, then try to add the time periods.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(t.h)) timediff, t.hc FROM 
(
SELECT start_time, end_time,
(  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start_time )  ) h, HOUR( start_time ) hc from history 
WHERE HOUR(end_time) = HOUR(start_time) AND start_time BETWEEN '2017-09-12 12:00:00' and '2017-09-12 15:00:00'
UNION
SELECT start_time, end_time,
(  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( end_time ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))) call_time, HOUR( end_time ) hc from history 
WHERE HOUR(end_time) > HOUR(start_time) AND start_time BETWEEN '2017-09-12 12:00:00' and '2017-09-12 15:00:00'
UNION
SELECT start_time, end_time,
(  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start_time )  ) call_time, HOUR( start_time ) hc from history 
WHERE HOUR(end_time) > HOUR(start_time) AND start_time BETWEEN '2017-09-12 12:00:00' and '2017-09-12 15:00:00'
) t GROUP BY t.hc
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To partition the time range up over the different hours to be grouped, you can join it to an ad hoc table of the hours you are interested in (untested):

```
set @max_duration_mins:=30;
select
    start_range,
    # overlap between two time ranges is the difference between the greater beginning time and the least ending time (or 0 if that's less than 0)
    sum(greatest(
        0,
        least(
            unix_timestamp(date_add(start_range, interval 1 hour)),
            unix_timestamp(end_time)
        ) -
        greatest(
            unix_timestamp(start_range),
            unix_timestamp(start_time)
        )
    )) total_seconds
from (
    select '2017-09-12 12:00:00' start_range
    union all select '2017-09-12 13:00:00'
    union all select '2017-09-12 14:00:00'
) start_range
cross join history
where start_time between date_sub('2017-09-12 12:00:00', interval @max_duration_mins minute) and '2017-09-12 15:00:00'
group by start_range;
```

A slightly more complicated approach, needed where there are an unbounded number of different partitions, would be to join history against an ad hoc table of how many whole hours into the history range to select (where in your case that would just be 0 or 1).  But I'm not going to show that unless you are interested.